# How to keep Star Colored once it has been clicked upon?

Tags: javascript

How do i keep a star colored after ive clicked on it and alter it if i click on a higher or lower rated star?

I want to create a Staring Component for my website

I can see the color of the star changing but on clicking on the star it doesn't stay.

```
<HTML>
<head>
.star{
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

#container{
  background-image: url('http://img1.targetimg1.com/wcsstore/TargetSAS/11_05_2013_06_55/images/ratings-large-sprite-r5.gif');
  width: 226px;
  height: 50px;
}
</head>
<body ng-app="RatingApp" ng-controller="RatingCtrl" ng-init="rating = star.rating + 1">
  <div id="container">
  <div id="1" class="star"></div>
  <div id="2" class="star"></div>
  <div id="3" class="star"></div>
  <div id="4" class="star"></div>
  <div id="5" class="star"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$("#1").mouseover(function(){
  $("#container").css('background-position', '0px -38px');
});
$("#2").mouseover(function(){
  $("#container").css('background-position', '0px -76px');
});
$("#3").mouseover(function(){
  $("#container").css('background-position', '0px -114px');
});
$("#4").mouseover(function(){
  $("#container").css('background-position', '0px -152px');
});
$("#5").mouseover(function(){
  $("#container").css('background-position', '0px -190px');
});

$(".star").mouseout(function(){
  $("#container").css('background-position', '0px 0px');
});</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to save the rating when a star is clicked. So far you're not listening for click events at all. You can do this by adding handlers with

```
$('#1').click(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

When the mouse moves out you could then restore the background position not to 0 but to the last clicked rating.

Here's an example on how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/e8hffqs5/